# Get line number for lambda using GDB

Tags: c++, lambda, gdb, name-mangling

We've a backtrace for a segfault that quotes a compiler-generated name for a lambda:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  std::_Function_handler<std::function<bool()>(), bold::AdHocOptionTreeBuilder::buildTree(bold::Agent*)::__lambda59>::_M_invoke(const std::_Any_data &) (__functor=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:2057
#1  0x08146d2c in operator() (this=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:2464
...
```

The assigned name is `bold::AdHocOptionTreeBuilder::buildTree(bold::Agent*)::__lambda59`. However as you can tell that file has a lot of lambda in it! Is there a way to map that generated function's name to a line number in the source code? We have line numbers for other functions, however here it's only quoted as a type param for `std::_Function_handler<>`.

Comment: Compile the file, introducing errors in the lambda bodies, see if the compiler spits out a name?  It may number them sequentially which coukd make searching fast.

Answer (score 1):

The linker option `-Map mapfile` should give you the information showing where each function originated, including lambda's. `nm --line-numbers` might work too, if the program was compiled with debug info `-g`.

Also, I think you can use `set print symbol-filename on` in GDB, and then evaluate `&bold::AdHocOptionTreeBuilder::buildTree(bold::Agent*)::__lambda59`

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I'll be sure to try this when I next reproduce the error.

Comment: Testing this out today I find that `nm` doesn't list any lambdas. The `set` command works, though does not change the information in the `backtrace`. Is there a specific command to use for evaluating the full type name? `print &bold::AdHocOptionTreeBuilder::buildTree(bold::Agent*)` works, but `print &bold::AdHocOptionTreeBuilder::buildTree(bold::Agent*)::__lambda59` gives _A syntax error in expression, near `__lambda58'._

Comment: @DrewNoakes: Tricky. When we say "lambda", we usually mean an unnamed object of an unnamed type, which always has an `operator()` member. `nm` shows functions, not types, but I guess the `std::_Function_handler` template parameter in your example is a type, not a function.